# In AppleScript, how to make code run if a button is pressed and other code run if a different button is pressed?

Tags: applescript

In Apple Script, I'm making a fake Virus as a prank and I want to know how to make it so if one button is pressed, some code is run and if a different button is pressed, other code runs.
Here's what I have so far:

```
display alert "Warning: Non-Standard hardware detected in 
core files. Please close all applications to allow 
maximum processing power."
delay 5
display alert "Warning: Non-standard hardware detected in 
core files. Core files may become corrupted."
delay 5
display alert "Non-standard hardware reaching dangerous 
level. If you would like to continue with purge process 
and risk your core files, click OK. If you would like to 
abort the process and leave the hardware, exit now." 
buttons {"Ok", "Cancel"} default button 1
```

I want it so if the user clicks the "Ok" button one thing happens and if they click "Cancel" another happens. I'm not experienced in Apple Script, this is my first script made in it.

Edit: I would also like to know how to make it auto-run when you double click it, because right now when I double click it Apple Script Editor opens and I just want it to instantly run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reformatted your code to make it easier to work with.  After editing it to your needs, just save it as an application in script editor.  Then double-clicking that new app will launch your script… Not script editor.

```
property displayAlert1 : "Warning: Non-Standard hardware detected in 
core files. Please close all applications to allow 
maximum processing power."

property displayAlert2 : "Warning: Non-standard hardware detected in 
core files. Core files may become corrupted."

property displayAlert3 : "Non-standard hardware reaching dangerous 
level. If you would like to continue with purge process 
and risk your core files, click OK. If you would like to 
abort the process and leave the hardware, exit now."

display alert displayAlert1
delay 5
display alert displayAlert2
delay 5
set buttonReturned to button returned of ¬
    (display alert displayAlert3 buttons {"Ok", "Cancel"} default button 1)

if buttonReturned is "Ok" then
    display dialog "Your Computer Will Explode In 1 Minute" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
        default button "OK"
else if buttonReturned is "Cancel" then
    display dialog "Your Computer Will Explode In 2 Minutes" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
        default button "OK"
end if
```

Comment: very much appreciated. That has answered my question.

Comment: @BobRoss Since you say it has answered your question, might I nudge you select this answer so **a)** people know the problem has been solved; **b)** other users with a similar problem are more likely to be directed here; **c)** the person who provided you assistance is rewarded with a token of your (demonstrable) appreciation.  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  It is, of course, your decision, so I only offer this suggestion in case you weren't aware that selecting was possible, or of the benefits it confers in the community.

Comment: @CJK thanks for alerting me to that feature, I wasn't aware that it existed. I have selected it.